# update object in an array if exists Push if not exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here my example document

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "principal" : "Joe",
    "classroom" : [
        {
            "grade" : "1",
            "class" : "A",
            "totalStudent" : 10.0
        },
        {
            "grade" : "1",
            "class" : "B",
            "totalStudent" : 20.0
        }
    ]
}
```

my goal is

1. increment TotalStudent when filter match ex.
   `principal : "Joe", classroom.grade: "1" classroom.class: "A"`
2. push new object into classroom if object isn't exists ex. `classroom.grade: "1" classroom.class: "C"`

my current query  (this work fine with increment into exists object)

```
db.getCollection("classsroom").updateOne(
    {
        pricipal: "Joe", 
        "classroom": {$elemMatch: {"grade":"1","class": "A"}}        
    },
    
    { $inc: { "classroom.$.totalStudent": 5 } },

    {upsert: true}
    
   
)
```

expect result

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "principal" : "Joe",
    "classroom" : [
        {
            "grade" : "1",
            "class" : "A",
            "totalStudent" : 10.0
        },
        {
            "grade" : "1",
            "class" : "B",
            "totalStudent" : 20.0
        },
{
            "grade" : "1",
            "class" : "c",
            "totalStudent" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using update/aggregation ( 4.2+ ):

```
db.collection.update({ "principal":"Joe" },
[
{
 $addFields: {
  x: {
    $size: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$classroom",
        as: "c",
        cond: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$$c.grade",
                "1"
              ]
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$$c.class",
                "A"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 },
{
$addFields: {
  classroom: {
    $cond: [
      {
        "$ne": [
          "$x",
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        $map: {
          input: "$classroom",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.grade",
                          "1"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.class",
                          "A"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    totalStudent: {
                      $add: [
                        "$$this.totalStudent",
                        5
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$classroom",
          [
            {
              "class": "C",
              "grade": "1",
              "totalStudent": 5
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
   }
  },
 {
   $unset: "x"
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Add temporary variable x that contain count of elements matching the criteria (grade="1",class="A")
2. Use the temporary variable x to check if array contain the matching element , if x=0 ( no elements matching ) perform concatArrays[] to add the new element. If x>0 (there is at least 1x element matching ) update the totalStudent value adding the needed increment amount.
3. Remove with $unset the temporary variable.
4. Add multi:true to perform the operation in all matching documents in collection

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W8c4rxqqcRm)

Improved version ( using $let for the temporary x variable ):

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/goW9PFjN64q)